# Script to combine multiple MySQL records into one via summing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm a MySQL newbie, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this. I've been looking through StackOverflow for quite a while, though, and haven't found it yet.

I have a MySQL table that is generated from a multi-reducer Hadoop MapReduce job which is analyzing log files. The table is being used in the database that supports a Ruby-on-Rails app, and it looks like this:

```
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
| id | src | dest |    time | requests  |
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
| 0  | abc | xyz  | 1000000 | 200000000 |
| 1  | def | uvw  |      10 |       300 |
| 2  | abc | xyz  |  100000 |    200000 |
| 3  | def | xyz  |    1000 |     40000 |
| 4  | abc | uvw  |     100 |      5000 |
| 5  | def | xyz  |   10000 |    100000 |
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to coalesce/sum the columns which have the same `src` and `dest`, but I just can't figure out how to do it even after searching through the MySQL 5.1 documentation.

I'm trying to write a script which I could run and obtain something like this at the end (neither the order of the rows nor the `id` column is important):

```
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
| id | src | dest |    time | requests  |
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
| 6  | abc | xyz  | 1100000 | 200200000 |
| 7  | def | uvw  |      10 |       300 |
| 8  | abc | uvw  |     100 |      5000 |
| 9  | def | xyz  |   11000 |    140000 |
+----+-----+------+---------+-----------+
```

Any ideas on how I could figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really combine the rows in a single table -- at least not easily.  That would require both updates and deletes.

So, just create another table:

```
create table summary_t as
    select src, desc, sum(time) as time, sum(requests) as requests
    from table t
    group by src, desc;
```

If you really want this go go back into the original table, then use a temporary table and re-insert the data:

```
create temporary table summary_t as
    select src, desc, sum(time) as time, sum(requests) as requests
    from t
    group by src, desc;

truncate table t;

insert into t(src, desc, time, requests)
    select src, desc, time, requests
    from summary_t;
```

However, having said all that, you should just add another step to your map-reduce application to do that final summary.

Answer (score 1):

`Group By` with `SUM` aggregate should work

```
select src, dest, sum(`time`) as `time`, sum(requests) as requests
from yourtable
group by src, dest
```

Comment: That's just a query, right? How do I replace the duplicated rows with the output of the query? (The table has 20 million+ rows, fyi)

Comment: I dont see  duplicated rows in your output

Comment: ahh, sorry, maybe I should edit the question. I'm trying to replace the rows in the first table (which have the same src and dst) with a single row that has the sum of the time and request columns. I know I can create a new table from your select statement, but the table is so big that I'm wondering if I have to create the whole thing again, or if there's something that's more efficient where I could do an in-table replace sort of thing. But I will try what you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this suite your needs, Create a table with the columns `src` and `dest` as primary key and other fields like `totaltime` and `totalrequest`.

Create an `INSERT AFTER` trigger on the existing tabl, which updates the other table `totaltime` and `totalrequest` with (old + new) using the `src` and `dest` as the key for where condition.